# Newsletter subscriptions list is not displaying in the stackexchange.com subscriptions tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, newsletter

I have subscribed for two newsletters (MSE, SO), it is listing in my ***Edit Profile & Settings -> Newsletters*** tab.

> [image: MSE]

But the same is not listing in my [Network Profile - subscriptions](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=subscriptions) tab.

> [image: Stackexchange.com]

Comment: Ah, yes - that shouldn't be there anymore... We're gradually deprecating things from SE.com and I missed that. Fix incoming

Comment: @DeanWard Do you mean, the subscriptions tab  from SE.com is going to be removed?

Comment: It will be, yes, everything is being rolled up into the network sites themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just pushed a build that removes this link. Newsletter subscription management has all moved to the network sites. You can manage all your newsletters in the [Newsletters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/newsletters/current) section of your profile.

In the coming weeks/months the remainder of the subscription management will be removed from stackexchange.com and migrated to the Q&A sites instead.