# Why did I automatically unsubscribe to about 75% of all my newsletters

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, newsletter

Since SE changed the mail sending address from "do-not-reply<at>stackexchange.com" to "do-not-reply<at>stackoverflow.email" I seem to lost all my newsletter subscriptions.

Before this change, I received the following newsletters:

- Home Improvement
- Theoretical Computer Science
- Software Engineering
- Software Quality Assurance & Testing
- Bricks
- Computer Science
- The Workplace
- Raspberry Pi
- Space Exploration
- Tor
- Earth Science
- StackOverflow
- Open Source
- Lifehacks
- Network enginering
- Reverse Engineering
- Electrical Engineering
- Meta Stack Exchange
- Server Fault
- Aviation
- Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
- Cryptography
- Skeptics
- Unix & Linux
- Webmasters
- Ask Ubuntu
- Arqade
- Information Security
- Web Applications
- Worldbuilding
- Android Enthusiasts
- Bitcoin
- Database Administrators
- Home Improvement
- Game Development
- Super User

However, after this change, I now only receive the following ones:

- Home Improvement
- Theoretical Computer Science
- Software Engineering
- Software Quality Assurance & Testing
- Bricks
- Computer Science
- The Workplace
- Raspberry Pi
- Space Exploration
- Tor
- Earth Science

What caused this, and how do I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Not sure if this is related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306103/newsletter-subscriptions-list-is-not-displaying-in-the-stackexchange-com-subscri

Comment: And this on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362372/email-for-newsletters-changed-without-any-notification/362375#362375

Comment: We made a large infrastructure change (basically, moving newsletters from stackexchange.com'd DB/code into Q&A sites). I passed this report along to the folks involved to look into, but in the meantime... Were you subscribed with the same email address to all those newsletters?

Comment: @rene (comment 1) In this case, the first one is not related, I first noticed this bug when SO was saying that I had to subscribe to the newsletter, (comment 2) I did notice this, but I got only 1 mail on monday instead of the usual 7

Comment: @AdamLear Yes, I was subscribed to all of them with the email address, I believe I setup most of the subscriptions using the SE interface in the past

Comment: @AdamLear I lost my Meta subscription this week.  It and two others always come on Thursday; today I received the other two but not this one, and when I investigated I found I was unsubscribed.  I got it last week.  Now I wonder what else is missing.

Comment: Damn, you need to take up a new hobby. I particularly like drinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like your account and about 500 others had a problem during the backfill for a major newsletter infrastructure change that occurred earlier in the week. I checked the logs originally but missed some failures towards the end.

Entirely my fault; I've fixed the issue and you're now subscribed to all the newsletters that you were subscribed to previously (as are the other 500 accounts).

Apologies for the inconvenience, I'll administer beatings as per usual protocol but myself because I work remotely.

Comment: Are you sure its working? While SE shows that I am now subscribed, no new newsletters have arrived in my inbox

Comment: @Ferrybig a few were sent yesterday; can you check your spam folder?

Comment: Got it figured it out, I had to visit my gmail label on my PC, before the new mails would show up in mobile, for some unknown reason, thx for your time